# Swedish characters in request body convert into '?' through WSO2 API Manager

Tags: rest, soapui, wso2, wso2-esb

As the title suggests -
I have REST APIs exposed through WSO2 API Manager. 
Sample request body for a POST operation is as below.

```json
{
   "name":"James",
   "country":"UK",
   "surname":"Bondäå",
   "town": "Brighton"
}
```

***Two observations:***
 - On invoking the rest endpoint directly - things work as expected.
 - On invoking the URL exposed by WSO2 API gateway manager the surname field gets converted into '**Bond??**'. That is the special characters äå convert to ??.

***Two important premises:***
 1. Rest client that I'm using is **SOAP UI**.
 2. When I hit the rest api console on WSO2 Store, then there's no problem .. the encoding of the characters is preserved.

Any help will be really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What is the SOAP UI version that you use? In SoapUI 5.2.1 this is supported by default.

This can be solved by setting the value of `Encoding` property in the `Request properties`  panel to 'UTF-8'

Comment: EDIT: My version - 5.2.1.
Had to add this property explicitly & did work. That's great.

But another angle to this problem still remains a mystery. Which is - why do I not need to add this property while I'm dealing with the WSO2 API Gateway's URL and not for the Rest end point directly.

Comment: API Console sets the 'charset'  to 'UTF-8' by default.

Comment: Thanks @asanthi. You are correct, 3 cases -
1. Rest end point - works fine.
2. API Console - works fine. (as suggested above)
3. the URL that WSO2 API Gateway publishes (with port 8243) - this is where I need to explicitly set the encoding to UTF-8. 
All I'm trying to understand is that why in the (#3 case) do I need to set the encoding property to UTF-8 in SOAP UI and not in the first 2 cases.
Ta